# textbox/form saved and reloaded

Tags: forms, text, save, edit

I have a question about textboxes or forms. I don't have any experience with them.

I would like to have a textbox/form where the user can type/copy text too.

There should be a save button and the saved text should be loaded and be editable again.

This isn't an internet application, so I don't need to specify a database of users.

Searching the web got me a lot of partial asp/.net/php solutions. I don't really know much of these.

My question is, would this be possible? And where should I start?

Thanx

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're trying to accomplish or what tech you're using. It sounds to me like a regular TextBox in a Winform can give you this functionality.

Comment: the tech would be a tablet. The textform should be a user generated summary of the page the are visiting. The second time they view the page their summary should be displayed again, and editable.

Answer (score 0):

I would use PHP for this, if you're unfamiliar there are some great learning resources at [W3 Schools PHP tutuorial](http://w3schools.com/php/) as well as the documentation at [PHP.net](http://php.net) you'll want to write an HTML form that submits to a php script. In  this script you can save text to a  file using the fwrite() function and load saved text using fopen(). Definitely have a look  through the w3 Schools php guide if you're new to this.

Comment: If php is the way to go here, I will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Is there an offline alternative? Correct me if I am wrong, but php always needs a server. I would like this to work in a folder with a text file and a HTML file. ( because it's an app and all the files will be on the users tablet)

Comment: If it's an app, web based languages are probably not the way to go. Server side languages such as PHP do need a server and client side ones like javascript can't access files. There may be alternatives but I think you'll probably have to use a full programming language like C. Try looking into SDKs like xcode for whichever platform you are developing for.